# Помогите с пользователями Gitlabа.

Tags: git, gitlab, centos

Установил Gitlab на centos 7. Все хорошо, все работает. Но ни как не могу зайти админом не по логину root, не по email. Пароль ввожу 5iveL!fe. В базе таблица users пустая.

Все решил сам. Переинициализировал БД.

Comment: @L0mka, Опубликуйте ответ на вопрос ответом или комментарием, мы отметим его верным.

Comment: Автор вопроса всё уже решил сам.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решился переинициализацией базы данных.

Comment: Ответ дождался своего голоса.